# How to fix "Fatal error compiling:invalid target release:10.0.2"

Tags: java, maven

After entering the command `mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=testng.xml` on cmd I am getting an error as `Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 10.0.2 -> [Help 1]`

Can anyone please let me know how to fix this issue?

I am providing output of some commands which I executed on my local windows10 machine.

1.java -version

```
java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)
```

2.echo %JAVA_HOME%

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\`

3.echo %MAVEN_HOME%

```
F:\path to directory\Maven\apache-maven-3.6.1
```

And following are some part of my pom.xml file

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>10.0.2</source>
                <target>10.0.2</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Also I already added `<java.version>10.0.2</java.version>` in pom.xml file.

Comment: try replacing 10.0.2 --> 10 for source and target

Comment: Use `<release>10</release` for JDK9+...with the appropriate level of JDK you would like to have at minimum..source/target/ alone is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used maven 3.5.1 with Java 10 yet but certainly the source and target version format needs some correction which should be similar to older versions :

```
<configuration>
   <source>10</source>
   <target>1.10</target>
</configuration>
```

Additionally, keeping the source and target version to 8 and 1.8 should also work for for maven 3.5.1 .

Hope this helps!